# How To re.sub def Consecutive Number

Tags: python

```
num = 0
def regex(m):
    num = num + 1
    return '<iframe src="%s%s%s">' % (m.group(1), '/number/', num)


re.sub('<iframe src="(\w+)">', regex, source)
```

source is

```
<p>hogehogehello<br />aaaa</p><iframe src~~><div><strong><h1>aa</h1></strong></div><iframe~~~><iframe~~~><h2>aaaaaa</h2><iframe~~~>
```

result

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

ideal

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/hogehgoe/number/1">
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/hogehgoe/number/2">
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/hogehgoe/number/3">
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/hogehgoe/number/4">
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/hogehgoe/number/5">
```

source ideal is

```
<p>hogehogehello<br />aaaa</p>
<iframe src~~/1><div><strong><h1>aa</h1></strong></div>
<iframe~~~/2>
<iframe~~~/3><h2>aaaaaa</h2>
<iframe~~~/4>
```

I do not want to use `finditer` if possible. I would like to complete with as short a code as possible.

I tried use global num. but Error SyntaxError: name 'bum' is assigned to before global declaration.

Comment: inside `def regex` try to put `global num`

Comment: i Tryed use global num but error message SyntaxError: name 'num' is assigned to before global declaration

Comment: @Aiven one should never recommend going for global variables.

Comment: sorry Aiven, You were right. solved the problem. def regex: global num. please answer not comment.